# Merged String Checker

Tags: python, python-2.7

At a job interview, you are challenged to write an algorithm to check if a given string, s, can be formed from two other strings, part1 and part2.

The restriction is that the characters in part1 and part2 are in the same order as in s.

The interviewer gives you the following example and tells you to figure out the rest from the given test cases.

For example:

'codewars' is a merge from 'cdw' and 'oears':

**s:  c o d e w a r s   = codewars**

**part1:  c   d   w         = cdw**

**part2:    o   e   a r s   = oears**

P.S: I am not able to solve the problem with my code. It's failing for some complex test cases, like the one for "Bananas from Bahamas".

I have tried to write a code. It passes for basic strings such as codewars. But it fails for some complex test cases such as 'Bananas from Bahamas'.

```
def is_merge(s, p1, p2):
    di_s={}    #Dictionary to hold the count of character in string s
    di_p={}    #Dictionary to hold the count of character in string p    
    p=p1+p2
    j=0
    k=0
    c=0
    txt=''
    for i in s:
        if i in di_s:
            di_s[i]=di_s[i]+1
        else:
            di_s[i]=1

    for i in p:
        if i in di_p:
            di_p[i]=di_p[i]+1
        else:
            di_p[i]=1



    if(di_s==di_p):    #To compare if the count of characters in s and p
        while(c<len(s)):
            if(j<len(p2)):
                if(p2[j]==s[c]):
                    txt=txt+s[c]
                    c=c+1
                    j=j+1
            if(k<len(p1)):
                if(p1[k]==s[c]):
                    txt=txt+s[c]
                    c=c+1
                    k=k+1
    else:
        return False
    if(txt==s):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

If:

```
s='Bananas from Bahamas'

p1='Bahas'

p2='Bananas from am'
```

The output should be 'True'. As string 's' can be formed from p1 and p2, given the current sequence of the characters.

Comment: Must all characters be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a function that recursively tries the next character in `p1` and `p2` for a possible match of the first character of the current given string, until the remaining string is empty, at which point return `True` if the remaining `p1` and `p2` are also empty:

```
def is_merge(s, p1, p2):
    return \
        p1 and p1[0] == s[0] and is_merge(s[1:], p1[1:], p2) or \
        p2 and p2[0] == s[0] and is_merge(s[1:], p1, p2[1:]) or \
        False if s else not p1 and not p2
```

so that:

```
is_merge('codewars', 'code', 'warss')
```

returns `False`, and that:

```
is_merge('codewars', 'cdw', 'oears'))
```

returns `True`, and that:

```
is_merge('codewars', 'cdw', 'oear')
```

returns `False` and that:

```
is_merge('Bananas from Bahamas', 'Bahas', 'Bananas from am')
```

returns `True`.

For cases where there are lots of overlaps between `p1` and `p2`, leading to many different paths and backtracking and consequently exponential time complexity, however, we can memoize the function with a dict of tuples of the remaining string and a frozenset of remaining `p1` and `p2` to cache the result so that no further recursion would be necessary when a suffix of `p1` is identical to that of `p2` and hence swappable as arguments:

```
def is_merge(s, p1, p2, cache=None):
    if cache is None:
        cache = {}
    key = s, frozenset((p1, p2))
    if key not in cache:
        cache[key] = \
            p1 and p1[0] == s[0] and is_merge(s[1:], p1[1:], p2, cache) or \
            p2 and p2[0] == s[0] and is_merge(s[1:], p1, p2[1:], cache) or \
            False if s else not p1 and not p2
    return cache[key]
```

Comment: IMHO this could use some line-breaks, and maybe an explanation of why `p1[0:1] == s[0]`, or split this up to `p1 and p1[0] == s[0]`?

Comment: Indeed. Updated as suggested for better readability then. Thanks.

Comment: @DavisHerring Indeed. I've updated my answer with a more optimized solution then.

Comment: @blhsing: The `frozenset` is a nice touch.

Comment: @blhsing

Thanks a lot for the answer. But it still fails for below test cases:

1)
s='codewars'
p1='code'
p2='warss'

Result should be 'False'

2)
s='codewars'
p1='codes'
p2='wars'

Result should be 'False'
3)
s='codewars'
p1='codewars'
p2=''

Result should be 'False'

Comment: @AyushGupta I see. You did not mention whether or not there can be leftover characters in `p1` or `p2` when `s` is fully formed so I assumed that there could be. I've updated my answer accordingly then.

Comment: @blhsing My bad. Thanks again :)